# QT Creator Can't read from stdin in debugger

Tags: c++, c, qt, debugging

I just updated QT Creator to 4.13.0 and now I can't read from stdin while I'm in the debugger.

A few details...

- I am running on macOS.
- I am writing C++, but using C stdio library. (for historical reasons)
- I am using clang 15.5.0 in c++11 mode.
- I am using the 'Run from Terminal' debugger option.

**Problem:** Type as I might, when my code goes into `fgets` it never returns.

**Simplified Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    if (fgets(buf,1024, stdin)) // In debugger, this call never returns!
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** When I run this outside of the debugger - no problems.

Has anyone run across this and fixed it? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: This is not the case for the "Run in Terminal" in Ubuntu so the issue appears to relate to specific console integration with Qt Creator.

Comment: By way of looking for workarounds I reinstalled QTC 4.13 and the problem persists. I also installed on Windows and Linux VMs. No problem there.

Comment: Have found a workaround. Rather than running the program from QTC, I run from a command line, and use the Debug menu option to "Attach to running application", or "Attach to unstated application".

Comment: Could you post a bug to Qt company? I only did it a couple of times when having company account but believe that individuals can do too: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Actually... I did that this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the terminal start application openTerminal.py inside QtCreator.

I had a similar issue, where the output of my console application appeared correctly in a terminal session when starting in debug mode without the debugger, but when starting using the debugger all system output and system error was written to Application Output widget making it impossible to read any values from std::in.

Solution was:
Manage Kits: Environment  System Replace the long path ".../openTerminal.py"
by "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"

Comment: this gives me `Cannot start the terminal emulator "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", change the setting in the Environment options.` (on Catalina 10.15.7)